# Merge with inner join

Tags: database, oracle, merge, inner-join

I am trying to merge an inner join so that I can use 3 different tables,
where TBL1 is the destination table where the records will be inserted,
TBL2 where all the records to insert in table 1 TBL1 live
and the third and last table TBL3 where a condition will be made by rfc,
where if tbl3.rfc = tbl2.rfc load the data to
TBL1. My query that I am doing is the following:

```
   MERGE INTO   TBL1 concent
        USING  (SELECT  inter.rfc,
                        arch.name_contr, arch.rfc,arch.taxpayer_situation, 
                        arch.oficio_global,arch.presumed_publication,arch.definitive_publication
        FROM TBL2 arch
        INNER JOIN  TBL3 inter 
              ON inter.rfc = arch.rfc )
        ON (concent.rfc = arch.rfc) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET concent.name_contr = arch.name_contr, concent.taxpayer_situation = arch.taxpayer_situation, concent..oficio_global = arch.oficio_global, concent.presumed_publication = arch.presumed_publication, concent.definitive_publication = arch.definitive_publication, concent.id_arch = arch.id_arch WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (concent.id_concent,concent.id_arch,conce.snapshot_date,concent.rfc,concent.name_contr,
            concent.taxpayer_situation,concent.oficio_global,concent.presumed_publication,
            concent.definitive_publication,concent.baja_logica,concent.last_update) VALUES (arch.id_arch, arch.id_arch,'04/05/2021',arch.rfc,arch.name_contr,
            arch.taxpayer_situation,arch.oficio_global,arch.presumed_publication,
            archi.definitive_publication,'01','05/05/2021');
```

The error it marks is: Command line error: 8 Column: 27 Error report - Error SQL: ORA-00904: "ARCH"."RFC":
invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause:
*Action:

database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of table aliases `arch` and `inter` is limited to that subquery only. If you want to specify columns from that subquery on the level of parent `merge`, you need to give alias to that subquery in `using` clause, for example `v_using`:

```sql
MERGE INTO   TBL1 concent
        USING  (SELECT  inter.rfc as inter_rfc
                        arch.name_contr, arch.rfc,arch.taxpayer_situation, 
                        arch.oficio_global,arch.presumed_publication,arch.definitive_publication
        FROM TBL2 arch
        INNER JOIN  TBL3 inter 
              ON inter.rfc = arch.rfc ) v_using
        ON (concent.rfc = v_using.rfc) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET concent.name_contr = v_using.name_contr, concent.taxpayer_situation = v_using.taxpayer_situation,...
```